# High CPU usage when getting color under cursor

Tags: c#, memory, cpu-usage, mouse-cursor

I'm working on an app, moving the mouse in a certain area and clicking the mouse if something is not the color black.

However, I am getting a really high CPU usage while using this method too get the color below the cursor. After 5 completed runs from startY to endY - the application is lagging that much it takes around 5-10 sec. to get too the end of the area. With this part commented out, the application runs fine and each run doesn't increase in the too complete.

Here is my while loop:

```
private void moveMouse(int startX, int endX, int startY, int endY)
    {
        int newPosX = startX;
        int newPosY = startY;
        while (running)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
            //this.Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
            Cursor.Position = new Point(newPosX, newPosY);
            Thread.Sleep(3);
            if (colorCursor.Get(newPosX, newPosY))
            {
                MyMouse.sendClick();
                countClicks++;
                lblStatus.Text = "Klik: " + countClicks;
            }

            newPosX += 10;
            if (newPosX > endX)
            {
                newPosY += 25;
                newPosX = startX;
            }
            if (newPosY > endY)
            {
                newPosY = startY;
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }
```

Color below cursor:

```
public class ColorUnderCursor
{
    [DllImport("gdi32")]
    public static extern uint GetPixel(IntPtr hDC, int XPos, int YPos);

    //[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    //public static extern bool GetCursorPos(out POINT pt);

    [DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetWindowDC(IntPtr hWnd);

    public bool Get(int x, int y)
    {
        IntPtr dc = GetWindowDC(IntPtr.Zero);

        long color = GetPixel(dc, x, y);
        Color underMouse = Color.FromArgb((int)color);
        if(underMouse != Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0))
            return true;

        return false;
    }
}
```

How I can minimize this heavy usage of the CPU.

**Solution:**
It was my method "Get" which was causing the problem. I solved it by this method below, and running the whole thing inside a backgroundworker.

```
public bool GetPixel(Point position)
    {
        using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(1, 1))
        {
            using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                graphics.CopyFromScreen(position, new Point(0, 0), new Size(1, 1));
            }
            if (bitmap.GetPixel(0, 0) != Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0) && bitmap.GetPixel(0, 0) != Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255))
                return true;

            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't think the sleep is the one causing the problem. If I remove the part where I call the colorCursor.Get(x,y) and the sleeps are still there - the application doensn't start hanging/lagging.

Comment: are you assuming heavy CPU usage because the program is lagging, or have you used a monitor to see that the CPU utilization actually is high?

Comment: DoEvents is a loaded weapon.  You aimed it at your foot here and pulled the trigger.  Use the Capture property instead.

Comment: I have used a monitor too check the CPU usage. 0 - 1% when the program is stopped and once running about 50% with the get color method.
Without that method, the CPU usage is high as well 50% - 80% how ever it ain't slowing the mouse movement down.

Comment: @HansPassant I need to be able to set running to false, by a hotkey. If I don't have this line, the while loop would run even though the hotkey is pressed. I am not familiar with the Capture property, would it work with the hotkey as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to move logic into Invoke call like this

```
private void moveMouse(int startX, int endX, int startY, int endY)
{

  this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { InvokeMouseMove(startX, endX, startY, endY)
   }));
}

private void InvokeMouseMove(int startX, int endX, int startY, int endY)
    {
        int newPosX = startX;
        int newPosY = startY;
        while (running)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
            //this.Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
            Cursor.Position = new Point(newPosX, newPosY);

            if (colorCursor.Get(newPosX, newPosY))
            {
                MyMouse.sendClick();
                countClicks++;
                lblStatus.Text = "Klik: " + countClicks;
            }

            newPosX += 10;
            if (newPosX > endX)
            {
                newPosY += 25;
                newPosX = startX;
            }
            if (newPosY > endY)
            {
                newPosY = startY;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I didn't work :(
I tried removing the sleeps, and shows out it runs really fast at first and gets slower and slower for each time. Could this method I am using too get the color below the cursor, really be that heavy too run?

Comment: I need to be able to set running to false, by a hotkey. If I don't have dovevents, the while loop keeps running even though the key is pressed. If I set a max run count for the loop, and when the while loop then stops, the running variable is set to false.

Comment: can you pass a delegate instead or something like this

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how this is done. I'll get back to you tomorrow, when I have some more time working on this.

Comment: It seems like that it were the method to get the color below the cursor, which were hanging the whole application. I found another way doing this which gave a lot better performance. I have added the code, to the topic.